# I'm trying to embed a webpage into my threeJS scene using CSS3DRenderer. For the same I followed several tutorials, but no luck so far

Tags: three.js

Following is my code, of the ThreeJS scene, I've checked and rechecked it several and there is no syntax error as well. But no luck so far. Sometimes it does give few Runtime errors in the imported script namely "Unable to get property 'center' of undefined or null reference"

Please Help help me out as I've to prepare this project by next week.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

  <script>

      var controls, camera, scene, cssScene, glRenderer, cssRenderer;

      function createGLRenderer()
      {
        var glRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha:true, antialias:true });

        glRenderer.setClearColor("rgb(255, 255, 230)");
        glRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        glRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        glRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        glRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
        glRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;

        return glRenderer;
      }


      function createCSSRenderer()
      {
        var cssRenderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();

        cssRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        cssRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        glRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 0;
        cssRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;

        return cssRenderer;
      }


      function createPlane(w, h, position, rotation)
      {
        var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "rgb(255, 0, 0)", opacity: 0.0, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

        var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, h);

        var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(material1, geometry1);

        mesh1.position.x = position.x;
        mesh1.position.y = position.y;
        mesh1.position.z = position.z;

        mesh1.rotation.x = rotation.x;
        mesh1.rotation.y = rotation.y;
        mesh1.rotation.z = rotation.z;

        return mesh1;
      }


      function createCssObject(w, h, position, rotation, url)
      {
        var html = [

          '<div style = "width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px;">',

          '<iframe src = "' + url + '" width = "' + w + '" height = "' + h + '">',

          '</iframe>',

          '</div>'

        ].join('\n');


        var div = document.createElement('div');

        $(div).html(html);

        var CssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);

        CssObject.position.x = position.x;
        CssObject.position.y = position.y;
        CssObject.position.z = position.z;

        CssObject.rotation.x = rotation.x;
        CssObject.rotation.y = rotation.y;
        CssObject.rotation.z = rotation.z;

        return CssObject;
      }


      function create3Dpage(w, h, position, rotation, url)
      {
        var plane = createPlane(w, h, position, rotation);

        scene.add(plane);


        var cssObject = createCssObject(w, h, position, rotation, url);

        cssScene.add(cssObject);
      }


      function initialize()
      {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

              camera.position.set(0, 100, 3000);

        //controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

        glRenderer = createGLRenderer();
        cssRenderer = createCSSRenderer();

        document.body.appendChild(cssRenderer.domElement);
        cssRenderer.domElement.appendChild(glRenderer.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        cssScene = new THREE.Scene();

        var alight = new THREE.AmbientLight("rgb(255, 255, 255)",0.5);
              scene.add(alight);

        create3Dpage(1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), 'http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile');

        Render();
      }


      function Render()
            {
        //controls.update();

                  glRenderer.render(scene, camera);

        cssRenderer.render(cssScene, camera);

                  requestAnimationFrame(Render);
            }

      $(document ).ready(function() {

        initialize();

      });

  </script>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you created a live example on codepen or another website like that.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a built-in snippet editor (in the formatting bar, it's beside "Insert Picture"), which embeds the code within the post (less chance of an external link going dead).